# Bringing custom splash screen to custom about box in NetBeans platform applications

Tags: java, netbeans-platform

Am trying to create a NetBeans platform application. I created my own splash screen. The splash screen appears in the default about box.

But when I customized the about box, the default splash screen of NetBeans appears.

This is the location of my splash img.
**branding/core/core.jar/org/netbeans/core/startup/splash.gif**

This is how I have tried to access it and failed.

```
getClass().getResource("/org/netbeans/core/startup/splash.gif")
```

Can someone please help me in getting my splash img in the custom about box?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is easy. Just right click to project - application, -> branding -> splash scree -> browse. ..

Comment: What you have said will help get my custom splash screen in the default about box. But question is how to get my custom splash screen in my custom about box.

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry for misunderstanding.

So it is easy too.

1) you modify App/important files/project properties add this line:

#for run

`run.args=-J-Dnetbeans.mainclass=splah.CustomStartup --nosplash`

#for run from IDE

`run.args.extra=-J-Dnetbeans.mainclass=splah.CustomStartup --nosplash`

2)create project JavaApplication splah and class CustomStartup, then build and copy the jar from dist to App/

```
package splah;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JWindow;


public class CustomStartup {

private static final String NB_MAIN_CLASS = "org.netbeans.core.startup.Main";
private static final int width = 500, height = 400;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // do whatever you need here (e.g. show a custom login form)
    System.out.println("Hello world! I am a custom startup class");

    JDialog splash = new JDialog();
    splash.setUndecorated(true);
    //
    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    splash.setBounds(width, height, (screenSize.width-width)/2, (screenSize.height-height)/2);
    splash.setVisible(true);

    // once you're done with that, hand control back to NetBeans
    ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    Class<?> mainClass = Class.forName(NB_MAIN_CLASS, true, classloader);

    Object mainObject = mainClass.newInstance();
    Method mainMethod = mainClass.getDeclaredMethod("main", new Class[]{String[].class});
    mainMethod.invoke(mainObject, (Object) args);

    splash.setVisible(false);
   }
}
```

The Class is not from my head, I found it somewhere, but I do not remeber where.

Jirka